# How to escape hash symbol(#) in netsh command

Tags: cmd, escaping, character, netsh, ssid

Our company main Wifi ssid is called "#TestRIG". I need to switch SSIDs during the automation test frequently.
I tried the command as below.

```
netsh wlan connect name="#TestRIG"
netsh wlan connect name=^#TestRIG
netsh wlan connect name=\#TestRIG
```

None of them worked.

> C:\Users\admin>netsh wlan connect name=^#TestRIG
> There is no profile "" assigned to the specified interface.

> C:\Users\admin>netsh wlan connect name="#TestRIG"
> There is no profile "" assigned to the specified interface.

Can anyone help to get the command to escape hash symbol?

Comment: Keep in mind that `name` does not take the SSID. In most cases profile name and SSID are the same, but not always.

Answer (score 1):

Not an elegant solution, but you could utilize the built-in "exec" command in `netsh` referring to a file. Example in PowerShell:

```
@"
wlan connect name="#TestRIG"
"@ | out-file c:\temp\netsh.txt -encoding ascii

netsh exec c:\temp\netsh.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue this week and I couldn't find any reference about which escape character to use. I solved using wildcards. It is possible to use '*' or '?' wildcards:
e.g:

```
netsh wlan connect name="*#TestRIG"
netsh wlan connect name="?TestRIG"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).